# R showing " r encountered a fatal error the session was terminated"

Tags: r

After running succesfully lots of application, I am facing one issue for 1 application. I open the application and then after I close the application/Operate inside application. I get below message . Not sure why. Not sure why. Can anyone help me

`````
"r encountered a fatal error the session was terminated" 
````
`````

Comment: I think we're gonna need more details than this... what application for starters?

Comment: It has some pyhton integration. Other than that, rest remains same as other applications that are working fine